T-SQL : throwing error when updating a column with an invalid value
Too many times I have had to try to resolve an issue where an invalid value was inserted into a row. Let's use gender for an example and let's for simplicity say the value can be 'M', 'F', 'U' or null. Some manager finds a 'Z' and asks you to discover how that 'Z' got into the database and resolve the issue. Let's also ignore that fact that that table might be modified in several different locations.
There are several solutions to this issue but I am trying to get different solutions on how people resolve these types of issues.
The best way is to get the frontend developer to ensure the value is valid before sending the INSERT or UPDATE statement to the server.  Let's assume that the frontend developer was inept, lazy or forgetful and this situation wasn't caught in testing.
Let's assume this is being done with either an INSERT or UPDATE statement or even with a trigger.
Not asking for help but find out how others resolve these kinds of issues.  You can check the parameter to ensure the value is in the range through a static list or a lookup table. There is no right answer while there may be solutions that aren't as beneficial.

CHECK  constraints are a good start: CHECK (YourColumn IN ('M', 'F', 'U')), or a foreign key to another table, so no bad data will ever get into the database, and the frontend devs will have to deal with the error.

Blocking a bad input in the future is a different problem from discovering how the bad input arrived.

For this specific case, I would create a table with a row and column for each allowed value, and then setup a foreign key relationship between the new table and the column from the existing table. SQL Server will then throw an error if someone tries to set a value to the existing column that does not match the foreign key.
From there, it is possible to disable enforcement of a key like this, but it's something that is rare to see in production and you'd have to be deliberate about. No one is going to bypass this by accident.

Another great answer.  Something I would like to hear somebody say during an interview.

Three solution inside the database...
FIRST as @Charlieface says, the CHECK CONSTRAINT is the best solution. To maximize the information to the user that will be blocked I define a strict standard for the name of my constraints like this:
CONSTRAINT FK_???_VALUE_DOES_NOT_CONFORM CHECK (YourColumn IN ('M', 'F', 'U'))

Where ??? is a unique trigram that define the table name.
When in client code, trap this error, extract the name (beginning by FK_) extract the trigram and the corresponding table name, then inform the user...
SECOND use a computed column, as an example:
CREATE TABLE T
(YourColumn VARCHAR(1),
 [ ] AS CAST(IIF(YourColumn IN ('M', 'F', 'U'), NULL, CONCAT(YourColumn, ''' when user fill the field "YourColumn"   ')) / 0 AS BIT) PERSISTED
)

THIRD use a trigger
Trigger has a heavy cost. Constraints are very light. Trigger is more complex to write...

Reason why I posted the question is that I am compiling a list of better questions to ask during a interview.  Most people can't answer the question and very few know about constraints.

As for triggers, I have seen large processes on a table take hours but when you remove the trigger those exact same processes take minutes.  I like triggers when you do something critical like updating a restricted column.  You don't want somebody giving themselves a raise without a notification.   Unless there is a critical need, triggers are something I don't like to see because it makes code more difficult to follow.
